# Why Most Mail Services Didn't allow some types of files like .exe in attachments?

Tags: email, architecture

What are technical difficulties to allow all type of files in mailing services. why there are no restriction in uploading file to cloud drives like google drive but for mailing services there are some limitation.

Here is an gmail attachment policy,clearly they don't allow certain type of files.
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6590?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a security policy to save the Users. It's not primarly made for the mail servers. The User should't receive mails with bad software.